# 200 ft race (with turnaround) where two people have different jump lengths but jump the same distance in equal time - who wins and by how much?

Tags: problem-solving

[image]

This problem is from Problem Solving Strategies - Crossing the River with Dogs and Other Mathematical Adventures by Ken Johnson and Ted Herr.

I decided to draw a picture from the segment of $90$ ft to $100$ ft of the race (the wall where they turn around). I chose to start at $90$ ft because both two and three go into 90 evenly, so neither Roo or Tigger are in the middle of a jump at that time.

Thus, at the $96$ foot mark, both Roo and Tigger are at the same spot. But, at the $98$ foot mark, Roo is about to jump to the $100$ ft mark and Tigger is mid-jump en route to the $99$ ft mark. So, when Roo jumps, he is at the $100$ ft mark and ready to turn around, while Tigger is on the $102$ ft mark and then waiting to turn back around.

I am having trouble trying to figure out how much Roo wins by then exactly. It's hard to tell from my picture, but I believe it would be $2$ feet. Is that correct, or does Roo possibly win by more? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roo travels $200$ feet to reach the finish line.

Since Tigger has to travel in $3$ foot jumps, Tigger needs to travel $102$ feet until (s)he can turn around.  Then Tigger needs to travel another $102$ feet to reach the start/finish line, a total of $204$ feet. The two jumpers travel at the same rate. So Roo is $4$ feet ahead of Tigger at the end, sort of.

This is in fact not necessarily the case, because it relies on a *specific model* of jumping. Since we were not given a detailed description of the jump processes of either creature, we are forced to assume *something*.  We implicitly assumed that even although the travelling is divided into jumps, the actual speeds are constant.

Suppose instead that a jump consists of standing in one place flexing the leg muscles for a while, and perhaps having a drink, while the movement part of a jump  is quick.  Then the answer need not be $4$ feet.

Comment: I don't see how you got that Roo was four feet ahead. How do you see Tigger travels 204 feet? I only see him jumping 2 feet extra from the first turnaround, meaning he jumps 202 feet.

Comment: He (or she) has to get back!

Comment: Ah, wow. Something so simple, yet I missed it; thanks.

Comment: @Jay: Tigger turns round after running 102 feet, so he has to run another 102 feet to get back to the start; that’s a total of 204 feet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it by counting jumps. Roo reaches the halfway point in exactly $50$ jumps, so he requires $100$ jumps to finish the race. Tigger reaches the $99$ foot mark in $33$ jumps, then takes $2$ more jumps to cross the $100$ foot mark and return to the $99$ foot mark, and finally needs $33$ jumps to return from there to the starting line, for a total of $68$ jumps. At $3$ jumps per second (or whatever the basic unit of time is), Roo finishes in $\frac{100}3$ seconds. In $\frac{100}3$ seconds Tigger makes $2\cdot\frac{100}3=\frac{200}3$ jumps, which is $\frac43$ of a jump, or $4$ feet, short of the $68$ jumps that he requires. Assuming that his speed is constant, he’s still $4$ feet shy of the finish line when Roo crosses it.

Comment: Nice alternative.